# Android Vitamio 5.0.0 library crash

Tags: android, live-streaming, vitamio

I updated Vitamio 4.2.2 to 5.0.0 as Google requested because of security issues in developer console. But with the same codes, it crashes like below:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "nulllibstlport_shared.so" not found
at java.lang.Runtime.load(Runtime.java:332)
at java.lang.System.load(System.java:981)
at io.vov.vitamio.MediaPlayer.<clinit>(MediaPlayer.java:257)
at io.vov.vitamio.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:431)
at io.vov.vitamio.widget.VideoView.setVideoURI(VideoView.java:403)
at io.vov.vitamio.widget.VideoView.setVideoURI(VideoView.java:396)
at io.vov.vitamio.widget.VideoView.setVideoPath(VideoView.java:392)
at com.mypackage.myapp.LiveStreamActivity$LiveStreamParse.onPostExecute(LiveStreamActivity.java:131)
```

The crash happens when I call `videoView.setVideoPath(liveStreamUrl);` as below:

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.vvSurface);
videoView.setVideoPath(liveStreamUrl);
final MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(LiveStreamActivity.this);
videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
videoView.setVideoLayout(VideoView.VIDEO_LAYOUT_STRETCH, 0);
videoView.requestFocus();
videoView.start();

videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
         mediaPlayer.setPlaybackSpeed(1.0f);
    }
});
```

When I look the sample of Vitamio 5.0.0, nothing changed for `VideoView`. So it seems Vitamio has totally ruined itself. Even though they published this release on 2015-11-02, they are still targeting SDK version to API 19. This is really shame.

Any suggestions for this unfortunate issue will be appreciated besides expecting appropriate answers from Vitamio team.

Comment: Nothing seems to work, compile several versions, no works with libvplayer.so, is the end of vitamio =/

Comment: I switched to ExoPlayer months ago, so I am not going to accept any answers.

Answer (score 1):

As it seems your app failing to found "nulllibstlport_shared.so" native library. And when it comes to native it's useful to specify the **particular device** on which problem occurs.

However, on Vitamio website they say that lib is currently supporting: ARMv6, VFP, ARMv7, NEON,MIPS,X86 etc...
So I suggest you try to **force your app include native libs only for supported ABI.**

For this you need to add this to *app/build.gradle*

```
defaultConfig {
    ...

    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips"
    }
}
```

and in the root folder of your project find *gradle.properties* file and add there **'android.useDeprecatedNdk=true'**

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.

# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
...
# org.gradle.parallel=true

android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

But I don't really know if this would help.

Comment: That's a shame it didn't help. But again: what device are you using?
Also try to unpack your .apk file and check the 'lib' folder. Check what folders(armeabi, x86, etc..) it has inside and **in which folders the nulllibstlport_shared.so is present?** If it present there at all...

Answer (score 1):

There is no LibsCheck class in Vitamio 5.0.
It's required to run in onCreate function.

It seems Vitamio 5.0 is not complited. It doesn't use ffmpeg library and it can't play.

Answer (score 1):

Late reply,

But this can work (Worked for me at least when I had same error)

```
 Vitamio.isInitialized(this);
```

Or

```
 Vitamio.isInitialized(getApplicationContext());
```

in onCreate of your activity.

Answer (score 0):

for solve specifically that problem, the thing that I did, was to modify the file *MediaPlayer.java*, located in *src/io/vov/vitamio/*.
On the line 253 says:

```
String LIB_ROOT = Vitamio.getLibraryPath();
```

and you should change it for:

```
String LIB_ROOT = "/data/data/your.package.name/lib/";
```

Anyway, if you are not sure, you can debug the app, stopping just in that line, and the variable LIB_ROOT, will have the complete route.

Now I have another problem making work this library. But I hope this help.