# Android Vitamio 5.0.0 crash initializing Library

Tags: android, live-streaming, vitamio

I updated the library Vitamio from version 3 to 5, following the instructions explained on this project: [StreamPlayeerVitamio5](https://github.com/ahpiau18/StreamPlayerVitamio5) in which the library is initialized as follows:

```
Vitamio.isInitialized(this);
```

Then on the MediaPlayer, I included the code necessary on info, as follows:

```
mPlayer.setOnInfoListener(new MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                switch (what) {
                    case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_FILE_OPEN_OK: // line added 1
                        long buffersize = mPlayer.audioTrackInit(); // line added 2
                        mPlayer.audioInitedOk(buffersize); // line added 3
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

After this, when trying to start the app, I had the problem described on this question: [Android 5.0.0 Library crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34599764/android-vitamio-5-0-0-library-crash), and I change it a part of code, for say directly to the app, were the *.so files are, but now I have the following error:

```
  I/Vitamio[5.0.0][Player]: LOAD FFMPEG START: /data/data/package/lib/libffmpeg.so
  E/Vitamio[5.0.0][Player]: FIND_NAME_SYM ffmpeg, ff_ass_split
  E/Vitamio[5.0.0][Player]: FIND_NAME_SYM ffmpeg, ff_ass_split_dialog
  E/Vitamio[5.0.0][Player]: FIND_NAME_SYM ffmpeg, ff_ass_split_free
  E/Vitamio[5.0.0][Player]: FIND_NAME_SYM ffmpeg, av_close_input_file
  I/Vitamio[5.0.0][Player]: LOAD FFMPEG END: /data/data/package/lib/libffmpeg.so
  I/Vitamio[5.0.0][Player]: LOAD VVO START: /data/data/package/lib/libvvo.9.so
  E/Vitamio[5.0.0][Player]: FIND_NAME_SYM vvo, render_yuv
  I/Vitamio[5.0.0][Player]: LOAD VVO END: /data/data/package/lib/libvvo.9.so
  I/Vitamio[5.0.0][Player]: LOAD VAO START: /data/data/package/lib/libvao.0.so
  I/Vitamio[5.0.0][Player]: LOAD VAO END: /data/data/package/lib/libvao.0.so
  I/Vitamio[5.0.0][Player]: VPLAYER INIT BEGIN
  I/Vitamio[5.0.0][Player]: Vitamio Version 5.0.0 
  I/Vitamio[5.0.0][Player]: Application package name: package
  D/Vitamio[5.0.0][Player]: RENDER RGB
  D/Vitamio[5.0.0][Player]: THREAD NOTIFY START
  D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 279K, 15% free 10283K/11975K, paused 17ms+4ms, total 41ms
  I/Vitamio[5.0.0][Player]: VPLAYER INIT END
 Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 5527 (astre.package)
```

Well, in this version the library don't show the spinner bar loading, so it seems to me that not all the elements are loaded on time. Does anyone had a similar problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this has something to do with text-relocations in the new bundle for 5.0 +

[Android Vitamio 5.0.0 crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34951420/android-vitamio-5-0-0-crash)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but text-rellocations itself is not a problem, it's a functionality as is showed here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4928.